# How long can I keep cooked food in a tupperware container outside of the fridge for?

Tags: food-safety, food-poisoning, refrigerate-refrigeration

[Here](http://www.safefood.eu/Food-Safety/Storing/Fridges.aspx) it says to throw away cooked food that has been left unrefrigerated for more than two hours. Is that the case even if the food's in a tupperware container?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this does not fit the scope of this site