# Food safety and implications of cooked food left un-refridgerated

Tags: food-safety, food-poisoning, refrigerate-refrigeration, raw-food

Expanding on the [question here](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3318/how-long-can-i-keep-cooked-food-in-a-tupperware-container-outside-of-the-fridge):

What are the health implications and safety hazards when one leaves food outside the fridge for longer periods (12-24hours for example) and how likely are those to happen? In essence, what are the risks short term or long term and how likely are those to occur approximately?

What is included in the high-risk food category described [here at bulletin 2](http://www.safefood.eu/Food-Safety/Chill/Chilling.aspx)?

Assume a mainly pasta/legumes/vegetables cooked in oil-based diet(Mediterranean diet) primarily, well cooked and well heated prior to consumption again, with food being left outside of sun radiation and room temperatures of 5-20 °C (winter-summer) for the aforementioned time period.

Comment: That second link you posted answers your questions.

Comment: If the probability of getting sick when leaving food at room temperature for half a day were high, then no one would do that and the guidelines would not be necessary. That's why we don't have guidelines saying that jumping from the tenth floor to the ground is not safe, but we do have guidelines about things like food safety, driving safely etc. etc.

Comment: @CountIblis surely, but Im more interested in  what would be the actual dangers long term or short term, be it highly probabilistic or low chance events. Edited the question to make this more clear.

Comment: @CareyGregory the link only described good food safety rules and guidelines to properly store food, not what is the actual dangers that can occur or how likely those are to occur (short term or long term).

Comment: Have you read the other topics at that link? They do address those issues.

Comment: @CareyGregory thank you, didnt notice the other topics on the side menu.

Comment: Read this answer also https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/34671/7632